# Assign op in TensorFlow: what is the return value?

Tags: python, assign, tensorflow

I was trying to build an autoincrementing graph in TensorFlow. I thought that the `assign` op might be suitable for that, but found no documentation for it.

I assumed that this op returns its value—like in C-like languages—and wrote the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

counter = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")

one = tf.constant(1)
ten = tf.constant(10)

new_counter = tf.add(counter, one)
assign = tf.assign(counter, new_counter)
result = tf.add(assign, ten)

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:

  sess.run(init_op)

  for _ in range(3):

    print sess.run(result)
```

and this code works.

The question is: is this the expected behavior? Why is the assign op not documented here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/index.html

Is it a non-recommended op?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `tf.assign()` operator is the underlying mechanism that implements the [`Variable.assign()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.assign) method. It takes a *mutable tensor* (with `tf.*_ref` type) and a new value, and returns a *mutable tensor* that has been updated with the new value. The return value is provided to make it easier to order an assignment before a subsequent read, but this feature is not well documented. An example will hopefully illustrate:

```
v = tf.Variable(0)
new_v = v.assign(10)
output = v + 5  # `v` is evaluated before or after the assignment.

sess.run(v.initializer)

result, _ = sess.run([output, new_v.op])
print result  # ==> 10 or 15, depending on the order of execution.
```

---

```
v = tf.Variable(0)
new_v = v.assign(10)
output = new_v + 5  # `new_v` is evaluated after the assignment.

sess.run(v.initializer)

result = sess.run([output])
print result  # ==> 15
```

In your code example the dataflow dependencies enforce the order of execution `[read counter] -> new_counter = tf.add(...) -> tf.assign(...) -> [read output of assign] -> result = tf.add(...)`, which means that the semantics are unambiguous. **However**, the read-modify-write steps to update the counter are somewhat inefficient, and can have unexpected behavior when there are multiple steps running concurrently. For example, multiple threads accessing the same variable could observe the counter moving backwards (in the case that an older value was written back after a newer value).

I would recommend that you use [`Variable.assign_add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.assign_add) to update the counter, as follows:

```
counter = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")

one = tf.constant(1)
ten = tf.constant(10)

# assign_add ensures that the counter always moves forward.
updated_counter = counter.assign_add(one, use_locking=True)

result = tf.add(updated_counter, ten)
# ...
```

Comment: We run the first code snippet and we only observed that the output can only be either 5 or 15.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies how tensorflow does assignments, which seems to be a bit different than how Theano does it. Is there also a way to safely refer to the value *before* the update? In the example above I'd like the result to be 5 while still updating `v` to be 10 after the call.

Answer (score 4):

`tf.assign()` is nicely [documented in the latest versions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) and it is used frequently in the projects.

> This operation outputs "ref" after the assignment is done. This makes
>   it easier to chain operations that need to use the reset value.

In easier words it takes your original tensor and a new tensor. It updates original value of your tensor with a new value and returns the reference of your original tensor.