# In dynamic_rnn() is it valid to include variables in the state?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm implementing a RNN cell around BasicLSTMCell where I want to be able to look back on past hidden states (across batch boundaries).  I'm using `dynamic_rnn()` and the basic pattern I use is:

```
def __call__(self, inputs, old_state, scope=None):
    mem = old_state[2]

    # [do something with with mem]

    cell_out, new_state = self.cell(inputs,
                                    (old_state[0],
                                     old_state[1]))

    h_state = new_state.h
    c_state = new_state.c

    # control dependency required because of self.buf_index
    with tf.get_default_graph().control_dependencies([cell_out]):
        new_mem = write_to_buf(self.out_buf,
                               cell_out,
                               self.buf_index)

    # update the buffer index
    with tf.get_default_graph().control_dependencies(new_mem):
        inc_step = tf.assign(self.buf_index, (self.buf_index + 1) %
                             self.buf_size)
        with tf.get_default_graph().control_dependencies([inc_step]):
            h_state = tf.identity(h_state)
    t = [c_state, h_state, new_mem]
    return cell_out, tuple(t)
```

`self.buf` and `self.buf_index` are variables. `write_to_buf()` is a function that uses `scatter_update()` to write the new hidden states to the buffer and returns the result.

I rely on the assumption that accesses to scatter updates return value guarantee that the new variable value is used (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148121/assign-op-in-tensorflow-what-is-the-return-value)) so that caching of variables does not mess things up.

From debug prints it *seems* to work but it would be nice to get some confirmation or suggestions on alternatives.

Comment: You could access `var.read_value()` to make sure it doesn't use cached value. This complexity will be made better with Resource variables (in HEAD you can do `tf.get_variable(..., use_resource=True)`) but not much docs yet

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried var.read_value() but I ran into issues because of the parallel nature of dynamic_rnn. Specifically, parallel iterations > 1 caused these reads to run immediately for all time steps of the batch.